# Develop ansible call another module

Tags: ansible

I am developing an a Ansible module for compile sources, like

`- source_compile:
    archive: /var/cache/sources/nginx.tar.gz
    configure:
       prefix: /usr`

I will probably

1. Check source package. (If is url download it)
2. Make a unique build directory.
3. Unarchive source to build directory.
4. configure && make && make install

So I want use ansible core module get_url and unarchive and shell, But no found how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute other modules only from action plugin, not from module itself.
It's done with `_execute_module` helper function. See [template](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/038e090bc1c208f8c02745a3a35821af99a64483/lib/ansible/plugins/action/template.py#L207) action for example.

Also you may be interested in using other helper functions such as `fetch_url` to retrieve remote data and `_low_level_execute_command` to run shell commands instead of calling other modules.

I'd recommend inspecting Ansible core modules/actions sources code to get the idea of how things work.

Comment: Thanks. I found ansbile run module code, ansible upload a ziped python library to remote work dir. runtime upload module to remote work dir and run module main fucntion.